# How to make dot replay embedded normal command? e.g in insert mode: <c-o>ysiw>Some<esc>

Tags: repeated-commands, operator

For example:

```
OpRef
  ^- cursor
```

I press `<c-o>ysiw>Option<esc>` in insert mode to get:

```
Option<OpRef>
```

I want to repeat this command with dot operator, but when I press dot it only replays the last part:

```
OpRef
  ^- cursor
```

Press dot:

```
OpOptionRef
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

This is using https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround to get that `ysiw>` behavior.

The `.` dot command works on individual changes.  The `ywis>` edit is the first edit and then typing Option is the second edit.

I recommend you record a macro with these keystrokes and then replay the macro.